# Assembly, how to find the max, number in array

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

[image]I'm new to assembly and I don't understand why the emulator is skipping line 6 and not increment at line 7

Please explain to me I'm so lost in this:

```
org 100h

x db 1, 2, 3, 3, 5

mov SI, 0 ;index

mov AL, 0       ;max
mov AL, x[SI]       ;assign max

mov SI, 1   ;initialize SI to 1

next:

cmp x[SI],AL

jg adding 

inc SI

cmp SI,4

JNE next

hlt 

adding:
mov AL,x[si]

inc SI

jmp next
```

here is an image, Al is suppose to be intitizailzed as x[0], which means its suppose to be 1, but i can see the value is 8B

[image]

Comment: Which of these is line 6?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of issues here:

- The initial `mov al,0` is not needed as you read the first value on the array in next.
- The "`adding:` code has no termination condition - it will read past the end of `x` You should share the end of array code between both parts.
- Even if your end of array check worked, it should be using 5, not 4. Consider using a label subtract or something to get this value from the code though.

Here are some suggestions:

```
org 100h 
mov SI, 0 ;index    ; Set index to 0

mov AL, [x+SI]       ; Assign max
inc SI              ; Next index

next:
cmp [x+SI],AL        ; Compare next array element
jg adding           ; If Greater, jump to adding

check_end:        
inc SI              ; Increment array index and check for end
cmp SI,5            ; Check is after increment, so it needs to be 5

jne next
hlt                 ; If done (SI == 5), halt

adding:
mov AL,[x+si]        ; Update AL with new max
jmp check_end       ; Jump to condition check

x db 1, 2, 3, 3, 5
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! im using an emulator, when im stepping over "mov AL, x[SI]       ; Assign max " AL is not changing, why is that?

Comment: Like Basically these two are skipped over and i don't understand why:mov AL, x[SI]       ; Assign max
inc SI              ; Next index

Comment: Basically we can run the progrram without these two lines:, org 100h 
x db 1, 2, 3, 3, 5

mov SI, 0 ;index    ; Set index to 0

next:
cmp x[SI],AL        ; Compare next array element
jg adding           ; If Greater, jump to adding

check_end:        
inc SI              ; Increment array index and check for end
cmp SI,5            ; Check is after increment, so it needs to be 5

jne next
hlt                 ; If done (SI == 5), halt

adding:
mov AL,x[si]        ; Update AL with new max
jmp check_end       ; Jump to condition chec

Comment: I just moved the base address into the `[]` above.  See if that fixes it for your assembler.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nc5Zv.png  please review this image of the compiler, for some reason, AL does not get  x[0] as max value at the beginning,it stills works but i dont understand why

Comment: There is a chance that your emulator is being really dumb and displaying bad instructions for the first few bytes because of the db array.  Try adding 4 or so 0s to your x array to see if that allows the debugger to show the data correctly.  You could also try placing your x array at the end of the code so that it can show better as then it isn't trying to display code and data as code at the same time.

Comment: @ItamarNahum: You put your data in the path of execution.  IIRC, `add [bp+si], ax` looks right for disassembly of `01 02`.

Comment: Ahhh - that is exactly right.  So putting the data at the end would have fixed it :)

Comment: @PeterCordes you mean to declare the x array at the end of the code? if so its still not working please review this image-https://i.stack.imgur.com/nc5Zv.png

Comment: @ItamarNahum: Yes, like in the duplicate, and like in Michael's update to this answer. Your image still shows `x db ...` at the start, causing exactly the same problem.  IDK what you mean "if so", because you didn't change that.  x86 machine code is a byte stream that's not self-synchronizing; your bytes of data get the CPU out of sync with the instruction boundaries in your source code; that's why decoding doesn't line up with the source for a while after the array.